# Clever variables : tabInt() , tabDouble(), tabChar(), etc. - How to implement these sort of variables?

Tags: c++

My name is Michael, 13 years, and I began to do C++ programming recently.

I have a book with following exercise:

> Create a class `myArray` that solves the overflow problem when
>   handling arrays. In addition, this new class will allow a user to
>   provide any integer (positive or negative) as the first index of the
>   table. Each object type `myArray` contains an array of any type noted
>   `Type`. When running, accessing an element of an array of type `myArray`, if there is buffer overflow (that is, if the index used
>   exceeds the size of the table in question) **the program must end with an appropriate error message.**

Let the following instruction:

```
myArray<int> tabInt(5); // (1)
myArray<double> tabDouble(2, 13); // (2)
myArray<char> tabChar(-5, 9); // (3)
```

The instruction (1) states `tabInt` as an array of 5 elements of type int : `tabInt [0]`, `tabInt [1]`, ..., `tabInt [4]`. The instruction (2) states `tabDouble` as an array of 11 elements of type Double: `tabDouble [2]`, `tabDouble [3]`, ..., `tabDouble [12]`. The instruction (3) states tabChar as an array of 14 elements of type char : `tabChar [-5]`, `tabChar [-4]`, ..., `tabChar [8]`.

Note the use of patrons of classes for the table represented by the myArray class can be of any type. For this, you must use the following notation when declaring the class myArray:

```
template <class Type>

class myArray{

private:

Type * Ptr;  //pointor on the array

int upperbound;
int lowerbound;

// Following declaration's class
}; // I must use this starting structure.
```

Furthermore, you will overload (overloading) the following operators in the class myArray :  `[]`, `==` and `!=`.

My question:

I have difficulties creating these variables `tabInt()` , `tabDouble()`, `tabChar()`, etc. Does someone could help me or just give me a good hint?

Comment: `tabInt`, `tabDouble` and `tabChar` are not functions, they are variables. Read about constructors and initialization in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't functions, they're objects. You are creating an instance of your `array<>` class, exactly as given in your instructions.

```
array<int> foo(5);  // create foo[]
foo[2] = 12;        // works fine
foo[5] = 99;        // complains?
```

Your instructions were truncated, so I don't know what your code is supposed to do if you try to access an element out of range.

Er... okay, fine. Here's more help:

Your `array<>` class should have two constructors:

```
template <typename T>
struct array
{
  array( int max_value ): _min_value(0), _max_value(max_value) { }
  array( int min_value, int max_value ): _min_value(min_value), _max_value(max_value) { }
private:
  int _min_value;
  int _max_value;
};
```

Comment: @george If you wish to use `class` instead of `struct`, that's fine, but you must be careful. A `struct` and a `class` are _identical_, **_except_** for the default visibility of member objects.

Comment: Could you offer me more details on the construction of tabInt() , tabDouble(), tabChar(), etc?

Comment: The first snippet I gave shows how it works. The names 'tabInt' and 'tabDouble' etc are just generic names your book used, just as 'foo' is a generic name I used. The name means nothing to the compiler -- it is only useful to us humans. Create your class, and make sure you have a constructor that initializes `upperbound` and `lowerbound` and you have everything you need to create your variables.

Comment: It's been a long time that I am on this issue. I know that I need to create a constructor to initialize my two variables `upperbound`
and `lowerbound`.  My question is asked about how to create the variables. Are you able to provide me more details about creating tabInt() , tabDouble(), tabChar(), etc?

Comment: Yes. Make your class. Then simply use it: `array<int> tabInt(5);` creates a variable (an instance of your array class) with 5 type `int` elements.

Comment: Could you give me two last details? "When running, accessing an element of an array of type `myArray`, if there is buffer overflow (that is, if the index used exceeds the size of the table in question) the program must end with an appropriate error message." How can I produce this sort of message? And how can I use the pointor Ptr in the class?

Comment: @george actually it's probably OK as it is, you will later add functions to `array` which do involve `T`.

Comment: @M.M Could you tell me if my program is right completely at the bottom of this page. If not, are there corrections can I make?

Comment: @george no it's not right. However I will not comment as you have posted it in the wrong place.  Your code should go in the question. Only answers go in the answer box.